# dockpanel.FloatForm is unexpectedly null

Tags: c#, devexpress

The following code is giving me a null reference.

```
foreach (DockPanel dockPanel in dockManager1.Panels){
dockPanel.MakeFloat();
tabbedView1.Controller.CreateNewDocumentGroup(tabbedView1.Controller.RegisterDockPanel(dockPanel.FloatForm) as Document); 
}
```

dockPanel.FloatForm specifically is showing as NULL in the debugger even though MakeFloat(); should set it http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDockingDockPanel_MakeFloattopic379

Comment: Ask at the DevExpress [Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/). That's what it's for.

Comment: I find more often than not Its a general Coding issue as opposed to a devexpress issue, but I'll go ahead and do that as well

Answer (score 0):

There are no reasons to use the [DockPanel.MakeFloat](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDockingDockPanel_MakeFloattopic379) method to make dock panels docked as tabbed documents. You should use the [DockPanel.DockAsMdiDocument](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDockingDockPanel_DockAsMdiDocumenttopic368) method.
Thus, the correct code should look like this:

```
foreach(DockPanel dockPanel in dockManager1.Panels) {
    if(dockPanel.DockAsMdiDocument()) {
        var document = tabbedView1.Manager.GetDocument(dockPanel) as Document;
        tabbedView1.Controller.CreateNewDocumentGroup(document);
    }
}
```